# c++ declare an array that is of type of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, header

I have a class, and in this class I'd like to have an array of another class, declares,  any suggestions on how to do this?

But when I do the following, I get an error.

```
 #include "classB.h"     

 Class classA
 {
 public:
 classA();


 int intArray[20];
 classB arrayOfClassB[20];
 };
```

I get:

> error C2512: 'classB' : no appropriate default constructor available.

My `classB` constructor takes a string.

Comment: @ Martinho,  when I do that, I get  error C2512: 'classB' : no appropriate default constructor available.   My classB constructor takes a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define an array in this way `classB arrayOfClassB[20];`, each element of `arrayOfClassB` will be constructed using the default constructor of `classB`. Since you have defined a constructor in `classB` which takes a string as a parameter, the compiler will **NOT** generate a default constructor of classB for you. In this case, you have to define a default constructor `classB()` in `classB`, then the error is gone. However, as others said, using vector is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an array (and the class that you are having an array of has a constructor that takes a string but does not have a default constructor), you have to initialise it in the constructor with the initialiser list:

```
 class classA
 {
 public:
 classA();


 int intArray[20];
 classB arrayOfClassB[20];
 };

 classA::classA() : arrayOfClassB({"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}) { }
```

There is no way around having to write the argument for every instance. So if your array is 20 big, you have to have 20 strings in the initialiser list.

It's probably less work for you to use a vector like this:

```
class classA
{
public:
classA();

int intArray[20];
vector<classB> arrayOfClassB;
};

classA::classA() : arrayOfClassB(20, classB("")) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize the `arrayOfClassB` array, the default constructor has to be called but the compiler is complaining since no default constructor is available. Default constructor is that constructor that takes no arguments.

As others have pointed out, you can either use `std::vector<classB>` or provide a default constructor and initialize the array later.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using vectors for that which should serve the same purpose and lets you create the array of your custom classes.

[C++ Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Comment: what couldn't I do that with an Array?

Comment: @Lexicon there is nothing you can't do with arrays that you can do with vectors. However this answer is a nonanswer because there is no question. Please edit your question to be very specific. We have no idea what you are asking or where you are having problems.

Comment: Sorry Seth, When I do the above, I receive an error stating that there is no appropriate default constructor available.  I dont plan on instantializing the arrary until to create an instance of classA.

Answer (score -1):

You could always define the array as a pointer type and create with `malloc`

```
classB **array;
static const int arrayElementLength = 50;

classA()
{
    array = (classB **) malloc(sizeof(classB *) * arrayElementLength);
    for (int i=0; i<arrayElementLength; i++)
        array[i] = NULL; //or construct with something else
}

~classA()
{
    if (array)
    free(array);
}
```